# How can I display a flash message using ajax after I reload the laravel view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a form in my laravel view. When I click on sendotp button, first there is database validation is done to check if that number already exists in the database or not, then accordingly it will return 0 or 1. If the number already exists then i.e. I receive 1 from the controller validation then I want to reload the page and display the flash error message "The phone number already exists.". Here is a small snippet of my code.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{url("ajax/checkphone")}}',
    method:'post',
    data:{'mobile_no':mobile,'user_id':user_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        if(obj.message=='1')
        {
            alert("Number already exists.");
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            //call the sendotp url and function.
        }
    }
});
```

The function is working properly as I tested it using the alert function.

Comment: Any console errors? By the way if you want reload first, than show `alert`, your have to swap places `alert("Number already exists.");` and `location.reload();`, don't you?

Comment: no console errors. Yes what you are saying about swapping the places is right. But i don't want to display the alert window box i want to display the laravel session flash message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Session::flash('message', 'Number already exists.');` in your controller. Need to validate in the controller and set the flash message.

Comment: but then the page will display the message everytime I open that particular page.

Comment: No, flash message will display only one time. Put this validation in your view file `if(Session::has('message')){ }`

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked for me. I added the error flash message in the controller in which i was returning 1 when i find the record. And i didn't need to add the validation of if(has('message')) one.